# Declaration of Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager Fatal_error on upgrade

Tags: magento2, php-7

When I'm Trying to upgrade my magento module i'm getting Declaration of Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager Fatal_error

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get($name, ?array $options = NULL)
>   must be compatible with
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::get($name, $options =
>   Array, $usePeeringServiceManagers = true) in
>   /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/PluginManager.php
>   on line 211

Help Me to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this error occurs when your **PHP Version is Not Supported and Not Compatible with your  magento 2 setup.**

if you are on linux then run **php -v** from command line and check which version of php are you using and check that  version is supported by magento setup.

**Refer this link for supported version of php by magento 2.2** - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

**Also to know more details about the issue refer this link -** https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Fatal-Error-Installing-on-XXamp/m-p/83571#M3441